# exclude an object from getting serialized

Tags: c#, json

```
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col].ToString().Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace(":", " ").Replace("\t", " ").Replace("/", " "));
    }
    parentRow.Add(childRow);
}


Jrep.status = "S";
Jrep.result = jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
Jrep.err_code = "";
Jrep.err_desc = "";
Jrep.Input = new Input { cabc= abc, cdbc= dbc, };
result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Jrep);
```

This is the code where I am serializing the dataset into json string.the next step would be to assign the json string to a member of the class and serialize the class but I dont want the already serialized object to again serialize.how can i stop this.Any suggestions appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: You can make Jrep.result to type List<Dictionary<string, object>> from string. you can avoid one serialization

Comment: Just a note: you are using two different serializers: `JavaScriptSerializer` and `JsonConvert` from Json.net

Comment: @heinzbeinz yaa I know it its the upgradtion I am doing later i will be using only one of them.

Comment: @viveknuna any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, But that wont be a clean solution. You can have a string, try to append data to it by some intelligence and set Jrep.result, But its not a good solution at all.

Comment: The "already serialized object" is now a string and strings must and will be serialized, but that's trivial. What exactly is your problem/goal?  Avoid 2-step deserialization? other?

Comment: @HenkHoltermanas i want the already serialized string to be avoided when next class serialization happens

Comment: And what does "avoiding a string" mean?  Try to ask questions in the form of expected vs actual results.